# Generate a custom geographic map geometry

Tags: d3.js, geojson, topojson

I am following [this](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/) guide to create a map visualization of Venice (Italy). Is there a way to generate such geometry? What I need is a GeoJson file representing the lines of the island (something like [this](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/step-3.html)).

I looked at [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/) but I don't understand how to export the GeoJson of Venice (or any other custom area).

**EDIT**:

Following the Stefanski's answer I generate the json, then I convert it to topojson using the following command:

```
topojson \
  -o venice.topojson \
  venice.json \
```

Then I copy the html code from the guide:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

/* CSS goes here. */

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 1160;

var projection = d3.geo.albers()
    .center([0, 55.4])
    .rotate([4.4, 0])
    .parallels([50, 60])
    .scale(1200 * 5)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

d3.json("venice.topojson", function(error, ve) {
  svg.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.feature(ve, ve.objects.venice))
      .attr("d", path);
});

</script>
```

This code does not give any javascript error but it **does not show the Venice map** whereas it works with the uk one.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use data from [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces.zip), using 'States and Provinces'. From there, use ogr2ogr to filter your data in GeoJSON format:

```
ogr2ogr \
-f GeoJSON \
-where "NAME = 'Venezia'" \
venice.json \
ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces.shp
```

As I am kind, I actually did it for [you](http://plnkr.co/edit/upJ2TVcZqgy6dtM44uP3?p=catalogue). You can then use this file as the ones for UK and build your map.